# GitLab error to access git lab, but i can access github

Tags: git, gitlab

im having this strange issue and i did't found any answers around.

I do pushes on gitHub ok, no problem.

In gitLab, i have this problem:

$ git push origin development
rafael@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights

And i do:
$ ssh -T git@gitlab.com
Welcome to GitLab, @barlera1989!
(seems like this works fine)

Then:
$ ssh -T rafael@gitlab.com
rafael@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
(seems like doesn't work)

I'm suspecting that i'm trying to push with a different email, as i see when i do git push.

Is possible to check / change that??

Note: My gitlab SSH key is fine!

I really have no idea whats going on!
Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commit email address and the git pull/push authentication are not the same thing.

You cannot use `rafael@gitlab.com` for Git push. When pushing to GitLab over SSH, the SSH username is always `git`, not your username. GitLab identifies you based on the SSH key, not the username.

If you already have a Git remote set up for your repository, update it like this:

```
git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com:YOUR_GROUP/YOUR_PROJECT.git
```

Replace `YOUR_GROUP/YOUR_PROJECT` with your actual values.

---

Separately, unless you work for GitLab, you should not be using `rafael@gitlab.com` or `git@gitlab.com` as your commit email address either. Your commit email address should be a valid email address that belongs to you.

Note that using `git config --global user.email EMAIL_ADDRESS` does not retroactively change the address on any commits you have already done. Also, you might have set `user.email` without the `--global` flag, meaning that it is stored in the local `.git/config` too - if that is the case, the local value overrides the global value.

(Also, it looks like the GitLab username `rafael` belongs to somebody else. You should not use other people's names in your questions. If you don't want to share your real username, use `example` instead, so everyone knows it has been changed.)

Comment: How do i change that? I'm suspecting that is the problem too....
I'm doing git config --global user.email "git@gitlab.com" . My ~/.gitconfig is showing as email: git@gitlab.com. But my pushes still showing rafael@gitlab.com

Comment: See updated answer.